# How to store organization specific configuration values in properties?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I'm developing a Gmail Add On with Google Apps Script, which is intended to be used only by enterprise accounts (Google Workspace Accounts).
One of the requirements of the app is that when the Admin installs the app for all its users, they have to configure some organization wide configuration values (a license key for example).

I tried with the following code:

```
const userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
userProperties.setProperty('licenseKey', '[TOKEN]');
```

But when I do this, the data is only accessible for the current user (and therefore I would need every user to know this key in order to save it on the configuration variables). I'm looking for an option in that a user saves this setting variable and then everyone on the domain can read the saved value.

Comment: Use `PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()` instead of `UserProperties`. Search official documentation.

Comment: @TheMaster if I understand correctly, by doing that ALL the users of the app will share the same configuration value. I'm looking for a way in that each organization has a different value for its users.

Comment: Hmm.. Maybe you could provide a external domain specific service? Alternatively, In script properties, `scriptProperties.setProperty('licenseKeyForOrganization1', '[TOKEN]');`, but I'm not sure whether you'll run into quotas

Comment: This question was discussed in official [chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/53357733#53357733)

Comment: @TheMaster thanks for your help. So it seems we'll have to use an external api to get this information. We were hoping to store this internally on the app but it's ok.

Comment: like I said, you could still try `scriptProperties.setProperty('licenseKeyForOrganization1', '[TOKEN]');`